# Convert (xls, xlsx) to CSV before Upload using PHP

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel

I am trying to convert an Excel file to CSV when user click on update button.

Its working when i upload one excel file in folder then i get that file using PHPExcel and read all data and convert it to CSV.

Here is the code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <?php
    ini_set("display_errors", "1");
    ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");
    ini_set("max_execution_time", "-1");
    error_reporting(1);

    require_once "PHPExcel.php";
    $dir = "../excel2csv/";                 // Main Directory Name 
    $file_arr = array();
    $file_ext_arr = array('xls','xlsx');            // Valid Extensions of Excel File

    // From Directory get only Excel Files in Array
    if(is_dir($dir))
    {
        if($dh = opendir($dir))
        {
            while(($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
            {
                $info = new SplFileInfo($file);
                $ext = $info->getExtension();           // Get Extension of Current File
                if(in_array($ext,$file_ext_arr))
                {
                    array_push($file_arr, $file);
                }
            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }

    // Make CSV File 
    $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'a');
    $list = array();

    foreach($file_arr as $val)
    {
        $arr_data = array();
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($dir . $val);
        $cell_collection = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellCollection();
        foreach($cell_collection as $cell)
        {
            $column = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getColumn();
            $row = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getRow();
            $data_value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getValue();
            //header will / should be in row 1 only. of course this can be modified to suit your need.
            // Skip Rows From Top if you have header in Excel then Change 0 to 1
            if($row == 0)
            {
                $header[$row][$column] = $data_value;
            }
            else
            {
                $arr_data[$row]['row'] = $row;
                $arr_data[$row][$column] = $data_value;
            }
        }
        $data = $arr_data;
        foreach($data as $val1)
        {
            $num_col = sizeof($val1) - 1;  // get number of columns in Excel 
            break;
        }
        $lwrcol=array();    
        foreach($data as $val2)
        {
            $alphaArr = range('A','Z');
            $colArr = range('A',$alphaArr[$num_col - 1]);

            foreach($colArr as $col)
            {
                $lwrcol[$col] = isset($val2[$col]) ? utf8_decode($val2[$col]) : "";
                fwrite($fp,$lwrcol[$col].",");
            }
            fwrite($fp,"\n");   
        }
        chmod(getcwd()."/file.csv", 0777);
    }
    fclose($fp);
    ?>
</html>
```

In above code first of all i am finding all excel files from folder and make one `file.csv` file.

What i want to do is when user select any file in `<input type="file" name="upload"/>` and click on UPLOAD button after then in backend first process is convert Excel file to CSV **BEFORE** it move to upload folder.

Comment: So as i can see your code is working for converting `Excel` to `CSV` but you haven't written code for uploading first from `input`. Correct?

Comment: all this code is in `<form action="file.php" method="post">`

Answer (score 1):

As i can see your code is working for saving data of `Excel` from `CSV`. But first you want to upload first from `FORM` then you want to convert. So this is what you can do is:

first you need HTML for `Form` and first upload file if POST file is there. Take a look in following snippet:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <?php
    ini_set("display_errors", "1");
    ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");
    ini_set("max_execution_time", "-1");
    error_reporting(1);


    require_once "PHPExcel.php";
    $dir = "../excel2csv/";                 // Main Directory Name 
    $file_arr = array();
    $file_ext_arr = array('xls','xlsx');            // Valid Extensions of Excel File



    if(!empty($_FILES)) {

        //uploading file first
        $info = pathinfo($_FILES['userFile']['name']);
        $ext = $info['extension']; // get the extension of the file
        $newname = "excelfile.".$ext; 

        $target = $dir.$newname;
        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'], $target);

        //upload finish  wiring csv file now
        writecsv();

    }

    function wirtecsv(){
        // From Directory get only Excel Files in Array
        if(is_dir($dir))
        {
            if($dh = opendir($dir))
            {
                while(($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
                {
                    $info = new SplFileInfo($file);
                    $ext = $info->getExtension();           // Get Extension of Current File
                    if(in_array($ext,$file_ext_arr))
                    {
                        array_push($file_arr, $file);
                    }
                }
                closedir($dh);
            }
        }

        // Make CSV File 
        $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'a');
        $list = array();

        foreach($file_arr as $val)
        {
            $arr_data = array();
            $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($dir . $val);
            $cell_collection = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellCollection();
            foreach($cell_collection as $cell)
            {
                $column = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getColumn();
                $row = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getRow();
                $data_value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getValue();
                //header will / should be in row 1 only. of course this can be modified to suit your need.
                // Skip Rows From Top if you have header in Excel then Change 0 to 1
                if($row == 0)
                {
                    $header[$row][$column] = $data_value;
                }
                else
                {
                    $arr_data[$row]['row'] = $row;
                    $arr_data[$row][$column] = $data_value;
                }
            }
            $data = $arr_data;
            foreach($data as $val1)
            {
                $num_col = sizeof($val1) - 1;  // get number of columns in Excel 
                break;
            }
            $lwrcol=array();    
            foreach($data as $val2)
            {
                $alphaArr = range('A','Z');
                $colArr = range('A',$alphaArr[$num_col - 1]);

                foreach($colArr as $col)
                {
                    $lwrcol[$col] = isset($val2[$col]) ? utf8_decode($val2[$col]) : "";
                    fwrite($fp,$lwrcol[$col].",");
                }
                fwrite($fp,"\n");   
            }
            chmod(getcwd()."/file.csv", 0777);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
    ?>


    <form action='' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='file' name='userFile'><br>
    <input type='submit' name='upload_btn' value='upload'>
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't want to move file in any folder before. I want the Excel file convert into CSV before its upload on server. 
When user select any excel and click on UPLOAD button at that time first process is Convert Excel file in CSV file and after convertion that file is upload in UPLOAD folder to use that in another process.

Comment: it's displaying empty page

Comment: @SriP i don't know right now actual cause of empty page. For this you have to debug your code step by step.